# Kids animated tv show from the late 80's

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I can only barely recall the images but thats it.  Will do my best to explain, you give me the title!

Main character; Female, white costume, has sort of flat hair with the rainbow streaks, touches a gold thing on her left shoulder to do stuff.

Then there is this large vessel (grey floating ship) that sort of transported all these characters through the show.  Sort of post-apocolyptic environment.  Can't remember.

Any ideas?

Comment: Was the main character an adult or a child? Also, was it anime (ie Japanese import and dubbed into English?)

Comment: Unfortunately have no idea!!  The main character was a teenager of sorts.  The other characters were younger.  As if she was taking care of them.  Seemed home-less

Comment: Were all the other characters human? Also, when you say "grey floating ship" are we talking about a boat which flies, or something more like a spaceship? Or maybe a blimp?

Comment: Gosh as I said it's a really tricky one.  I think the characters were human.  The A.I. that travelled with them looked a bit like a spaceship that hovered just above the ground.  It sort of had a square nose...

Answer (score 4):

Could it be "[Spartakus and the Sun Beneath the Sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartakus_and_the_Sun_Beneath_the_Sea)"?

It was one of my favourite shows when I was a kid. It has the female lead character, Arcana doing stuff by touching her shoulder, there is a hovering / flying ship with a square nose and some kids as main characters.

Here's the youtube intro:

Comment: Hey!  This is it!!  Wow thanks.  Weird how this stuff sticks in your head...Going to live through some of it quick

Comment: Hey, glad I could help. Could you please mark my answer as the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Is it [Jem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jem_%28TV_series%29), which aired from 1985 to 1988? The main character, when in hologram mode, has light pink hair which sometimes looks white in the animation, and in some illustrations has streaks in it (such as merchandise). Her non-hologram form, Jerrica, has light blonde hair which separates into flat-ish sections.

[image: Jem animated]
[image: Jem illustration]
[image: Jerrica]

Jerrica touches her earring, which contains a small projector, to activate the hologram (to appear as her rock star persona Jem using the power of Synergy, a gigantic holographic computer).

[image: projector earrings]
[image: Syngery computer]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for the answer above...